# Translating algebraic expressions inorder to postorder in javascript

Tags: javascript, inorder, postorder

I recently got an assignment to translate whatever algebraic expression from inorder to postorder using javascript. I have been following this guide to understand the concept and then tried to create the code necessary to complete my task.

http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/infix-postfix/

Here is my complete example:

http://wwwlab.iki.his.se/~a12aleny/PVU/

The code used to complete the task,ignore the comments, it's just jibberish in swedish:

```
var string = "";

function in2Post() {
var equation = document.getElementById('inputin2post').value;
console.log(equation);
var stack = new Stack();
string = "";
for (var i = 0; i < equation.length; i++) {
    var re = /[a-z]/;
    var status = re.test(equation.charAt(i));
    if (status === true) {
        string = string + equation.charAt(i);
    } else {
        if (stack.getlength() == 0) {
            stack.push(equation.charAt(i));
        } else {
            stack.compareOp(equation.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i <= stack.getlength();i++){
    string = string + stack.pop();
    console.log("bug");


}
var result = document.getElementById("result");
result.innerHTML = string;
console.log(string);

}
function Stack() {
this.stac = new Array();
this.pop = function () {
    return this.stac.pop();
}
this.push = function (item) {
    this.stac.push(item);
}
this.getlength = function () {
    return this.stac.length;
}
this.compareOp = function (operator) {
    var topOfStack = this.stac.pop(); //Hämta operatorn överst i stacken.
    if (operator == "+" || operator == "-") { //Om operatorn som skannas är ett plus eller minus.
        if (topOfStack == "-" || topOfStack == "+" || topOfStack == "*" || topOfStack == "/") { //om operatorn överst i stacken är plus, minus, gånger eller division.
            string = string + topOfStack; //lägg den poppade operatorn i string.
            if (this.stac.length == 0) { //Om stacken är tom.
                this.stac.push(operator); //Lägg på operatorn på stacken.
            } else {
                this.stac.compareOp(operator); //Om den inte är tom, kör funktionen igen med samma operator.
            }

        }
    } else if (operator == "*" || operator == "/") { //Om operatorn är gånger eller division.
        if (topOfStack == "+" || "-") { // om toppen av stacken är plus eller minus.

            this.stac.push(topOfStack);
            this.stac.push(operator); //Lägg operatorn på stacken.

        }
        else if(topOfStack == "*" || topOfStack == "/"){ // Om toppen av stacken är gånger eller division.
            string = string + topOfStack; // Lägg toppen av stacken i strängen.
            if (this.stac.length == 0) { //Om stacken är tom.
                this.stac.push(operator); //Lägg på operatorn på stacken.
            } else {
                this.stac.compareOp(operator); //Om den inte är tom, kör funktionen igen med samma operator.
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Please could someone explain why it doesn't operate as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around with it in the past. I have it done here:

You want the execution_order function.

http://www.ccesp.puc-rio.br/mostrapuc/imgs/logo/mc/mathcaio/math.js

Comment: Could you, with your experience of creating code for this purpose spot the error in my own code? It would be really helpful!

Comment: I used a method that enveloped the numbers in parenthesis before translating them into postorder. I didnt create the algorithm, I got it on the wikipedia in C and translated it to Javascript. The only improvement I did was to treat unary minus and trigonometric functions.